# Remove repeated elements in a 2D array in Fortran

Tags: function, fortran, fortran90

I would like to know whether it is possible to have a function that erases all of the 2D repeated nodes from an array, i.e.:

> A(xy,1:2)
>
> A(xy,1) = /1,2,4,**5**,5,9,6,8,2,**5**,4/
>
> A(xy,2) = /5,2,5,**6**,7,6,6,3,7,**6**,6/

After

> A(xy,1) = /1,2,4,**5**,5,9,6,8,2,4/
>
> A(xy,2) = /5,2,5,**6**,7,6,6,3,7,6/

---

When I try to execute @HighPerformanceMark's code in a blank program, there are several compiling errors that I do not get:

```
  repeating.f90:24.20:

       mask(ix) = NOT(ANY(arraya(1,:ix-1)==arraya(1,ix).AND.&
                      1
  Error: 'i' argument of 'not' intrinsic at (1) must be INTEGER
  repeating.f90:29.11:

    ALLOCATE(index_vector, source=PACK([(ix, ix=1,numcols) ],mask))
             1
  Error: Array specification required in ALLOCATE statement at (1)
  repeating.f90:32.11:
...
```

What can you say about this?

Comment: Sorry about that, I used `not` when I should have used `.not.` and my compiler didn't complain.  I've now edited my answer so try again. As to your 2nd problem are you sure that your compiler implements sourced allocation ?  It's a new-ish feature and recent versions of popular compilers are at various stages of 2003 implementation.

Comment: Hi again Mark, indeed, now the compiler only complains for the ALLOCATE orders, so I guess I don't have them. I am using F90, and I am quite newbie with fortran, could you facilitate how to download these library or feature for sourced allocation?

I actually can allocate some arrays, but this order is kind of new for me.

Comment: Sourced allocation is a feature of Fortran 2003 that not all compilers implement.  Your recourse is to acquire a compiler that does implement the feature, that's not something I can help you with.

Comment: It is possible to to do `ALLOCATE(index_vector(count(mask)), source=`, gfortran of certain versions does not like sourced allocation without the bounds specified. Sourced allocation per se is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's one way of doing what you want.  Note that this will copy the unique elements of array A into a new array called B rather than resize A on the fly.  I've called the arrays `arraya` and `arrayb` because 1-character names go against my coding standards.

```
PROGRAM test

  USE iso_fortran_env

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: numrows = 2
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: numcols = 11

  INTEGER, DIMENSION(numrows,numcols) :: arraya
  LOGICAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: mask
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: arrayb
  INTEGER :: ix
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: index_vector

  arraya(1,:) = [1,2,4,5,5,9,6,8,2,5,4]
  arraya(2,:) = [5,2,5,6,7,6,6,3,7,6,6]

  ! First, find the duplicate elements
  ALLOCATE(mask(numcols))
  mask = .TRUE.

  DO ix = numcols,2,-1
     mask(ix) = .NOT.(ANY(arraya(1,:ix-1)==arraya(1,ix).AND.&
                    arraya(2,:ix-1)==arraya(2,ix)))
  END DO

  ! Make an index vector
  ALLOCATE(index_vector, source=PACK([(ix, ix=1,numcols) ],mask))

  ! Now copy the unique elements of a into b
  ALLOCATE(arrayb, source=arraya(:,index_vector))

END PROGRAM test
```

Note also:

- I've written this as a program, you might want to rewrite it into a function which returns what I've called `arrayb`.
- There's no error checking or any of that sort of stuff, this is not production-ready code.
- You could probably dispense with `index_vector` and rewrite the last statement like this `ALLOCATE(arrayb, source=arraya(:,PACK([(ix, ix=1,numcols) ],mask)))` but (a) that's a wee bit cryptic and (b) I haven't tested it.
- I've only tested this on your input data and a few minor variations.
- This keeps the first (leftmost) instance of duplicated elements.

Comment: Given the SOURCE= specifier requires F2003 anyway, it's probably clearer to just use assignment rather than the last two allocate statements.  The need for the index_vector array here makes me wish that PACK had a DIM argument or similar.

Comment: So if I cannot do it that way with F90, which order should I place here? after the loop with the masked array?

Answer (score -2):

I extended this function and used for my purpose for years which I thought is beneficial to distribute to others who need it. ! ErrorMsg is just a simple subroutine like echo/print statements.

```
    subroutine Unique2DArray_D(Arr_a,dim,dup,diff)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  real*8,DIMENSION(:,:),allocatable::Arr_a,Arr_b
  integer,intent(in),optional::dim
  integer,allocatable,optional::dup(:)
  real*8,optional::diff
  LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:), allocatable::TF(:,:),mask
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),allocatable::index_vector
  INTEGER::i,j,numrows,numcols,ns,dim_
  real*8::diff_
  logical::pres_dim,pres_dup
  numrows=size(Arr_a,1); numcols=size(Arr_a,2); 
  pres_dim=present(dim); pres_dup=present(dup)
 ! Arr_a(1,:)=[1,2,4,5,5,9,6,8,2,5,4]
 ! Arr_a(2,:)=[5,2,5,6,7,6,6,3,7,6,6]
 dim_=1; if(pres_dim)dim_=dim; diff_=1d-20; if(present(diff))diff_=diff
 if(dim_==2)then
    ALLOCATE(mask(numcols),TF(numrows,numcols)); mask=.TRUE.;
    DO j=numcols,2,-1
        TF(:,j-1)=.false.
      do i=1,numrows
        TF(i,:j-1)=(abs(Arr_a(i,:j-1)-Arr_a(i,j))<=diff_)
      end do; 
      mask(j)=.not.any(all(TF(:,:j-1),dim=1))
    END DO
    ! Make an index vector
    ns=size(PACK([(i,i=1,numcols)],mask));   
    ALLOCATE(index_vector(ns)); index_vector=PACK([(i,i=1,numcols)],mask)
    ! Now copy the unique elements of a into b
    if(pres_dup)then; 
        allocate(dup(numcols-ns)); dup=PACK([(i,i=1,numcols)],.not.mask)  
    end if
    ALLOCATE(Arr_b(numrows,ns));   Arr_b=Arr_a(:,index_vector)
 elseif(dim_==1)then
  ! Arr_a(:,1)=[1,   ! Arr_a(:,2)=[5,]
!               2,                 2,  
!               4,                 5,
!               5,                 6,
!               5,                 7,
!               9,                 6,
!               6,                 6,
!               8,                 3,
!               2,                 7,
!               5,                 6,    
!               4]                 6]

    ALLOCATE(mask(numrows),TF(numrows,numcols)); mask=.TRUE.;
    DO i=numrows,2,-1
        TF(i-1,:)=.false.
      do j=1,numcols
        TF(:i-1,j)=(abs(Arr_a(:i-1,j)-Arr_a(i,j))<=diff_)
      end do; 
      mask(i)=.not.any(all(TF(:i-1,:),dim=2))
    END DO
    ! Make an index vector
    ns=size(PACK([(i,i=1,numrows)],mask));
    ALLOCATE(index_vector(ns)); index_vector=PACK([(i,i=1,numrows)],mask)
    ! Now copy the unique elements of a into b
    if(pres_dup)then; 
        allocate(dup(numrows-ns)); dup=PACK([(i,i=1,numrows)],.not.mask)  
    end if
    ALLOCATE(Arr_b(ns,numcols)); Arr_b=Arr_a(index_vector,:)
    !ALLOCATE(Arr_b,source=Arr_a(index_vector,:))
 else
    call ErrorMsg('Dim is incorrect in Unique2DArrayD!',-1)
 end if
  call move_alloc(Arr_b,Arr_a)
end subroutine Unique2DArray_D
```